# Changing text fields in Fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I am developing a map application. One activity has two fragments, where one is the map and the other is created `onMarkerClick()`. There are text fields in the `Fragment` and I need them to be changed after clicking on the marker for specific marker location and info. My marker Class:

```
public static BlankFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2,String param3,String param4,double param5,double param6) {
    BlankFragment fragment = new BlankFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("addressLine", param1);
    args.putString("countryName", param2);
    args.putString("imageURL", param3);
    args.putString("comment", param4);
    args.putDouble("lat", param5);
    args.putDouble("lng", param6);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        addressFromIntent=getArguments().getString("addressLine");
        countryFromIntent=getArguments().getString("countryName");
        commentFromIntent=getArguments().getString("comment");
        photoPath=getArguments().getString("imageURL");
        latFromIntent=getArguments().getDouble("lat", 0);
        lngFromIntent=getArguments().getDouble("lng", 0);
        addressView=(TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView);
        countryView=(TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        latlngView=(TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        saveButton=(Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.button);
        saveButton.setText("Save");
        imageView=(ImageView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        commentView=(EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText);

        final String latlngTextField=String.valueOf(latFromIntent)+", "+String.valueOf(lngFromIntent);
        latlngView.setText(latlngTextField);
        if (photoPath.equals("")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
        } else {
            imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(photoPath));
        }
        commentView.setText(commentFromIntent);
        commentView.setHint("Enter comment here...");
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dispatchTakePictureIntent();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), photoPath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        commentView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                commentModified++;

            }
        });
    }
}
```

My main activity `onMarkerClick()` method:

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    CustomMarker customMarker = list.get(new LatLng(marker.getPosition().latitude,marker.getPosition().longitude));
    getFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.map, BlankFragment.newInstance(customMarker.getAddressLine(),customMarker.getCountryName(),customMarker.getImageURL(),customMarker.getComment(), marker.getPosition().latitude,marker.getPosition().longitude))
        .addToBackStack(null) // enables back key
        .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_ENTER_MASK) // if you need transition
        .commit();
```

I am getting a null pointer when trying to set the button text (so as the other fields). How can I solve this?

Edit: the line `saveButton=(Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.button);` does not work with `getActivity()` either.

Comment: use inflated view to find views. `view.findViewById();`call this in `onCreateView` method

Comment: can you clarify? Im not so good with this yet

Comment: `addressView=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);` call these in `onCreateView` method in fragment after you inflate your fragment layout.

Comment: `saveButton.setText("save")` causes same null pointer even if i move them in `onCreateView()`.

Comment: Just checked and textViews are being created if i dont set them. So i know moving them into `onCreateView` works just as well but setting isnt working for now

Comment: it worked. Moved `onCreateView()` above `onCreate()` and now its ok. Thanks man :)